# Python Twisted for long data

Tags: python, networking, twisted

Python coders

I am working with twisted for build a server, which receive 3000 bytes of data on each connection, my issue is that packages are been truncated and stored on database as on  packages pieces,  What I am looking for, is a way to solve this kind of data packages that must be parsed as a one long data.

Line received is not a way, cause this kind of data is sent withuot a delimiter, Then I am thinking on a way of loop, however I am not completely sure of it or how to implement

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import binascii
from Datagram import *

class LingServer(Protocol):


    def __init__(self):
        print 'Staring Ling Server'
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        try:
            print 'Accepted connection'
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  Connection was not started"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Connection lost ", reason  

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            print "Data received ", data
            data = binascii.hexlify(data)
            Datagram (header=data[:10], content=data[10:])
            session.commit()

            #self.transport.write(self.decoder.processDatagram(data))
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  That was no valid data.  Try again..."


class LingFactory(Factory):  

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return LingServer()

reactor.listenTCP(12345, LingFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is stream-oriented.  See [the FAQ entry for this topic](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith).

If you want to buffer up 3000 bytes before processing, see `twisted.protocols.stateful.StatefulProtocol`.  For example:

```
class LingServer(StatefulProtocol):
    def getInitialState(self):
        return self.ling, 3000

    def ling(self, data):
        # Process here, len(data) == 3000
```